# Does Tcl eval command prevent byte coding?

Tags: tcl, eval, bytecode

I know that in some dynamic, interpreted languages, using eval can slow things down, as it stops byte-coding.
Is it so in Tcl 8.5?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't prevent bytecode compilation, but it can slow things down anyway. The key issue is that it can prevent the bytecode compiler from having access to the local variable table (LVT) during compilation, forcing variable accesses to go via a hash lookup. Tcl's got an ultra-fast hash algorithm (we've benchmarked it a lot and tried a lot of alternatives; it's *very* hot code) but the LVT has it beat as that's just a simple C array lookup when the bytes hit the road. The LVT is only known properly when compiling a whole procedure (or other procedure-like thing, such as a lambda term or TclOO method).

Now, I have tried making this specific case:

```
eval {
    # Do stuff in here...
}
```

be fully bytecode-compiled and it mostly works (apart from a few weird things that are currently observable but perhaps shouldn't be) yet for the amount that we use that, it's just plain not worth it. In any other case, the fact that the script can't be known too precisely at the point where the compiler is running forces the LVT-less operation mode.

On the other hand, it's not all doom and gloom. Provided the *actual* script being run inside the `eval` doesn't change (and that includes not being regenerated through internal `concat` — multi-argument `eval` never gets this benefit) Tcl can cache the compilation of the code in the internal representation of the script value, LVT-less though it is, and so there's still quite a bit of performance gain there. This means that this isn't too bad, performance wise:

```
set script {
    foo bar $boo
}
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    eval $script
}
```

If you have real performance-sensitive code, write it without `eval`. Expansion syntax — `{*}` — can help here, as can helper procedures. Or write the critical bits in C or C++ or Fortran or … (see the critcl and ffidl extension packages for details of cool ways to do this, or just `load` the DLL as needed if it has a suitable `*_Init` function).

Comment: The above is about the same in 8.5 and 8.6, though the latter bytecode compiles more commands overall.