# accelerate Tcl eval

Tags: performance, tcl, eval

I'm currently writing a Tcl-based tool for symbolic matrix manipulation, but the code is getting slow. I'm looking for ways to accelerate my Tcl code (Tcl version 8.6).

I have one suspicion. My code builds lists with a command name as the first element and command arguments as the following elements (this comes from emulating an object-oriented approach). I use `eval` to invoke these commands (and this is done often in the recursive processing). I read at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/eval and https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Performance that `eval` may be slow.

I have three questions:

1. What would be the fastest way to invoke a command from a list with command name and parameters which is constructed just beforehand?
2. Would it accelerate the code to separate the command name `myCmd` and the parameter list `myPar` and invoke the command with `[$myCmd {*}$myPar]` instead (suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27619692/3852630)?
3. Is the trick with `if 1` instead of `eval` still promising in 8.6?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you have something like `set cmd [list mycmd arg1 arg2 ...]` then you can invoke it with just `{*}$cmd`.

Comment: I suspect your code may be slowing down due to passing around a lot of data. Have a look at http://wiki.tcl.tk/K particularly the "Unsharing Objects" section.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks a lot. I had a look at the "K" page, but I was confused by the `$someVar[set someVar {}]` construction: What is it doing? Appending `{}` to the value of `someVar`?

Comment: First, the variable is expanded, then the command substitution sets the variable to hold an empty string (which is, somehow, a special value for Tcl),and the result of the command substitution (set returns the value) is appended to the _previous_ value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above all, don't assume: `time` it to be sure. Be aware when timing things that repeatedly running a thing *may* change the time it takes to run it (as caches warm up). Think carefully about what you want to *actually* get the speed of.

The `eval` command is usually slow, but not in all cases. If you give it a list *that you've constructed* (e.g., with `list` or `linsert` or `lappend` or…) then it's fairly fast as it can avoid reparsing the input; it knows, but *only* in that case, that it can skip straight to dispatching to the command implementation. The other case that is fast is when you give it a value that was previously given to `eval`; the bytecode is already built and cached. These notes also apply with `uplevel`.

Doing `$myCmd {*}$myParameters` is fairly fast too; that's bytecoded into “assemble the words on the Tcl operand stack and do the right command dispatch” which is very close to what it would be for an arbitrary user command anyway (which very rarely have direct bytecode implementations).

I'd expect things with `if 1` to be very quick in some cases and very slow in others; it forces full compilation, so if things can be cached well then that will be fast and if things can't it will be slow. And if you're just calling a command, it won't make much difference at all at best. The cases where it wins are when the thing being called is itself a bytecoded command *and* where you can cache things correctly.

If you're dealing with an ordinary command (e.g., a procedure, or one of Tcl's commands that touch the OS), I'd go with option 2: `$myCmd {*}$myParameters` or variants on it. It's about as fast as you're going to get. But I would not do:

```
set myParameters [linsert $myOriginalValues 0 "literal1" [cmdOutput2] $value3]
$myCmd {*}$myParameters
```

That's ridiculous. This is clearer and cleaner and faster:

```
$myCmd "literal1" [cmdOutput2] $value3 {*}$myOriginalValues
```

Part of the point of expansion syntax (`{*}`) is that you don't need to do complex argument marshalling, and that's good because complexity is hard to get right all the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot (again)! I used your last suggestion which in my case is `${cmdName}.what {*}$cmdPars` (where `.what` is a "method" of the "object" defined by `cmdName`). I got a 30% reduction compared to my `eval` solution, but this is confounded with other changes. Omitting `return` and just using this as the last command in a `proc` seems to improve the runtime a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

A note about [`K` and unsharing objects](http://wiki.tck.tk/K)

Avoid copying data in memory. Change

```
set mylist [linsert $mylist 0 some new content]
```

to

```
set mylist [linsert $mylist[set mylist ""] 0 some new content]
```

This dereferences the value of the variable and then sets the variable to
the empty string. This reduces the variable's reference count.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117854/7552

Comment: That's known as the K trick because I wrote the first version of it using the K combinator. However, it turns out that the version you see above does effectively the same thing without the overhead of calling a procedure (because concatenation with the empty string is a special case).

Comment: Interesting, I think I get it now, thanks. Besides `linsert` and `lreplace`, for which list commands would you use this trick? (Not for `lappend`, since it has a list variable as argument. Not for `concat` probably, since https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/concat recommends using `list` and  `{*}`.)

Comment: Just curious: If the penalty is that severe, wouldn't if have been better to design `linsert` and `lreplace` with a variable argument (as in `lappend`) instead of a value argument, or provide two versions of these functions? Or wouldn't that help?

Comment: Would you also recommend the K technique for `set listVar [list {*}$listVar {*}$arg]`, so would you use `set listVar [list {*}$listVar[set listVar ""] {*}$arg]`?